# MySQL: How to update colum1 if value does not exists in column 2

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a value into a column "email_new", but only if this value does not exist in a second column called "email". This means none of the entries in the column email should contain the new mail-address.

This is for a programm to change the email-address, where the email-address has to be verified, and the column "email" allows only UNIQUE values.

```
"
UPDATE `table`
SET email_new = '".mysql_real_escape_string($newmail)."'
WHERE
  user = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'
  && email NOT CONTAINS('".mysql_real_escape_string($newmail)."')
"
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Are you going to do this in a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes its possible but you could just use `email != '".mysql_real_escape_string($newmail)."'`

Comment: Why is the user equal to email too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not checking wheter the newmail is really unique:

append to your query another AND condition, something like:
    AND 0 = (select count(*) from table where email =  mysql_real_escape_string($newmail))

Comment: I just realized that MySQL 4.0 seems not to support subqueries,... So it seems that I have to send two seperate queries until the database is updated,...

Comment: This can be a workaround: 1)start a new transaction 2) check if the newmail already exist in the database table: if no 3) execute te update and then commit transaction if yes 4) abort transaction. if your system has many users transaction avoids sort of race conditions that can lead to duplicated email adresses

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = "
    UPDATE
        `table`
    SET
        `email_new` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($newmail) . "'
    WHERE
        `user` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($newmail) . "'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            `email`
        FROM
            `table`
        WHERE
            `email` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($newmail) . "'
    )
";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET email_new = ?
WHERE
    user = ?
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM table WHERE email = ?)
```

Replace `?` signs by actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply

```
UPDATE `table`
SET email_new = IF (email IS NULL, ?, ?)
-- this line is if you want to update email if email is not null
, email = IF (email IS NOT NULL, ?, ?) 
WHERE ...
```